# Align text over switch button - android studio

Tags: android

I'm working on my first app.

And I was wondering is there an option to to align a text on top of the switch button instead of right or left?

At the moment I can set the text to the right side or the left side of the switch button.

I know the easy way is just to add a text view. But this is really interesting to me:

[image: switch button]

Comment: You should add **textview** above to **switch** and keep switch text empty/null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add `textview` above to `switch` and keep switch text `empty/null`.

For example

```
   <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/switchTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add 3 Beeps" />

        <Switch
            android:id="@+id/switchButton"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/switchTitle"
            android:text="@null" />
    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: This was the easiest method.. I wonder if there is another option directly from the switch xml values.